# Large Gap Between Cells in UITableView, iOS Bug?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Anyone up for an interesting UI challenge? If so, you've come to the right place! I have a `UITableViewController` in Swift, with self-resizing cells (they use `autolayout` as opposed to the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` function). You can see from my screenshots that there is an odd gap in between the cells, and if you look at the screenshot of the UI capture, you can see that the problem is probably not that the cells are laying out wrong, there is actually no table view cell in the space. The wholes tend to jump around somewhat randomly when I start searching in the search bar, but often go away all together when I set a sort (using the filter scope selector that is attached to the search bar, shown in the second image).

As a HS student developer, I really, really appreciate any help you can give me with this! Although I wouldn't call myself a beginner at iOS, I am certainly no veteran at dealing with UIs.

Ur the best Stack Overflow community!

[image: Gap]
[image: Gap While Searching]
[image: UI Capture from <code>Xcode</code>]

Comment: If you have self-resizing cells with Auto-Layout then the problem is almost certainly with your layout constraints and/or code and not an iOS bug. You need to provide much more information if you want help. If the height of your cells varies then I think you **have to** implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Thanks Duncan, what details would be helpful to you? I'm pretty confident that my layout constraints work, they are pretty simple, and a problem with them should not cause the cells to have a gap. A problem in the layout constraints would be pretty visible in the UI capture (i know because I initially DID have problems with this, which I then fixed). Also, no, you DO NOT HAVE to implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath` anymore. [This explains how to avoid using this function.](https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is horrible, but it just "magically" fixed itself. The only possible explanation is that it was fixed because of the sketchy-ish code I added to get the sort/filter selection buttons to always show.

```
    searchController.searchBar.showsScopeBar = true
    searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, height: 88)
```

It was happening all the way up until I added that line. If anyone can explain exactly why this fixed it, that would be cool. I have a couple of ideas, but I'm really not sure.

It ended well at least.

***EDIT***

This is not the entire answer. Having cells of different heights also causes the problem, the weird thing with the search controller just seemed to alleviate part of it.

Pura Vida